# sp_msforeachdb in dataset

Tags: powershell, dataset, sp-msforeachdb

Can someone tell me why the following code only returns one row from the DataSet (for the master db) instead of one for each database on the server?

```
 $SQLConn = New-Object System.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = $SQLServer; Initial Catalog = master;
                             Integrated Security = True"
 $SQLConn.Open()

 $query = "exec sp_msForEachDb 'use [?] SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysusers'"

 $SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlCommand($query, $SQLConn);
 $SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 $SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCmd
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
 $SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | out-null

 ForEach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0])
 {
    $Name = $row["name"]
    write-host $Name
 }

 $SQLConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows your using the index position 0 of $dataset.tables. Change it to `$DataSet.Tables`

```
ForEach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0])
 {
    $Name = $row["name"]
    write-host $Name
 }
```

Change to...

```
 ForEach ($row in $DataSet.Tables)
     {
        $Name = $row["name"]
        write-host $Name
     }
```

Comment: That returns an error message:  "Unable to index into an object of type System.Data.DataTable"

Answer (score 0):

You're returning getting multiple datatables in your result set, but only showing the first one Tables[0]. Try this:

```
$DataSet.Tables | foreach {$_.name}
```

Here's some completed and tested code to combine result set:

```
$SQLServer = ".\SQL1"
$query = @"
create table #output
(DB varchar(128),
name varchar(128)

)
exec sp_MSforeachdb  @command1='USE [?];
insert #output SELECT TOP 1 ''?'' AS ''DB'', [name]
FROM sysusers';
select * from #output
"@



$SQLConn = New-Object System.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = $SQLServer; Initial Catalog = master;
                             Integrated Security = True"
 $SQLConn.Open()


 $SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlCommand($query, $SQLConn);
 $SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 $SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCmd
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
 $SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | out-null

 $DataSet.Tables[0]

 $SQLConn.Close()
```

Comment: that returns nothing.  but this returns the entire dataset I'm looking for:  $DataSet.Tables | foreach {$_}.  Why does it have an issue with the "name" field?

Comment: OK, maybe I can't use a dataset to do this?  I guess I didn't realize at first that it's putting records from each database into a *different* dataset table.  So, when I attempt to loop through it, I either get records from one table, or an error because it can't loop through different table objects?  Maybe it's better to just insert everything into a #tmp table in SQL Server and then insert into my main table when it's done.  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I needed to do something like this to get *all* of the records into *one* dataset:

```
 $query = "DECLARE @users TABLE ([name] varchar(100)) INSERT @db_roles 
           exec sp_msForEachDB 'USE [?] SELECT [name] FROM sysusers'
           SELECT [name] FROM @db_roles"
```